# How to LISTEN and alert on ESTABLISHED connection (low-interactive honeypot)

Tags: linux, security, email, monitoring, tcp

What is the most robust solution for a super-simple linux daemon that just LISTENS on some port(s) and every time a connection is ESTABLISHED, it immediately sends me an email alert?

I'm building a [low-interaction honeypot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)#Types) inside my production network. I found that most of the open-source "honeypot" solutions are way more complex than what I need.

I just want a simple daemon to listen on some "valuable" ports (eg `22`, `139`, `3389`, `5900`, etc) and send me an email alert if anything connects to it.

Valid solutions could be to use a an open-source project already available, or to just a simple bash/perl/python script -- as long as it can be daemonized to a service that will start on boot.

Comment: Use iptables to log SYN packets and then alert on log entries.

Comment: This is a great resource that lists lots of honeypot-related projects https://github.com/paralax/awesome-honeypots

Comment: That sounds like a great way to spam-dos yourself. The honey trapper trapped itself

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this with the `wazuh` HIDS (Host-Based Intrusion Detection System) and some firewall rules.

First, [install wazuh](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/index.html)

- https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/index.html

And configure it to send email alerts by updating `/var/ossec/etc/rules/local_rules.xml`

```
<email_notification>yes</email_notification>
```

Then, edit your wazuh local rules file, adding this inside the default group

```
  <rule id="100001" level="7">
    <if_sid>4100</if_sid>
    <description>Attempt to connect to honeypot</description>
  </rule>
```

The above rule matches firewall rules (rule id `4100` defined in `/var/ossec/ruleset/rules/0060-firewall_rules.xml`) and alerts any time a firewall rule spits out a log. You can further refine it, but for a low-interaction honeypot in your prod intranet that's not publicly accessible or used by your staff, this should be fine.

You may also need to update your decoders to parse the entry. Add this to `/var/ossec/etc/decoders/local_decoder.xml`

```
<decoder name="iptables-3">
   <parent>kernel</parent>
   <type>firewall</type>
   <prematch>^[\s*\d+.\d+] IN=</prematch>

   <regex>^[\s*\d+.\d+] \.+ SRC=(\S+) DST=(\S+)</regex>
   <order>id,srcip,dstip,protocol</order>
</decoder>

<decoder name="iptables-3">
   <parent>kernel</parent>
   <type>firewall</type>
   <regex offset="after_regex">^SPT=(\d+) DPT=(\d+) </regex>
   <order>srcport,dstport</order>
</decoder>
```

Create an iptables rule that just logs every time a TCP connection is made to port 22. And persist it.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j LOG
apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

This will log an entry in the kernel log every time someone attempts to connect over ssh to your server. You can repeat it for other common ports, such as common ports for RDP, domain controller, databases, etc.

And restart wazuh

```
systemctl status wazuh-manager
```

You'll now get an email alert any time someone connects to the server on port 22.